# How to set default email on the Activity Tag for Opportunity?

Tags: opportunity, activity

I have 4 email addresses in my org as Organization Wide Email. How can I set a particular email as default email in Activity tab?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pre-defined the **from** field in your email action.
[image]

Then select the email address in specific field dropdown which you want to be default in your email action.
[image]
it would work.

Comment: Thanks, it works...In my case it worked from Global Action..